# How do I prevent that references in my formula change when I copy the formula to a new cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to use submitted Google Form data in one spreadsheet to locate and retrieve data from another spreadsheet (tab in same document). [The Google Spreadsheet file is here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhNVNg1xSJ6-dGpvdFJGMmpuWExWeUE2SWhFQ21Wb3c&usp=sharing)

The `=QUERY` statement I'm trying to use is this:

```
=QUERY(sheet2!A1:K; "Select B, C where A =" & B1  ; 0)
```

It works if I remove the *cell reference* from `where A =" & B1  ; 0)` and I replace it with a *static value* like `where A contains '123456' ")`.

Any suggestions on how to get the `=QUERY` to work using a cell=referenced value? The heading for the column being referenced is TEXT but the value of all rows below the heading is a NUMBER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that the data row reference changes when you drag-copy the formula down. It needs to be made static. So instead of

```
sheet2!A1:K
```

you need to write

```
sheet2!A$1K
```

or in this case (as you're starting from row 1 anyway), you can use:

```
sheet2!A:K
```

Comment: Tom, thank you. Your change helped. The problem I have now is my spreadsheet is populated by a Google Form and the =QUERY doesn't auto fill down. Any suggestions?